# Converting ArrayList to HashSet

Tags: android, arraylist

I am having a difficulty upon converting arraylist to hashSet. I dont have knowledge about HashSet that why I use ArrayList. I've read some about it but understand none. I am here trying to get some help about my problem.

All I wanted is to NOT DUPLICATE the words entered in my app's ListView. Here's my code. Please bear with it. I've seen some questions too here but it got me a lot more confused. Please be nice.

**P.S.**  My first try :)

```js
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
//onCreate
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
  wordList.setAdapter(adapter);

//SEARCH
public void viewWord(View view) {
        s1 = search.getText().toString();
        s2 = dbHelper.getData(s1);

        if (optionTxtView == 0) {
          tv2.setText(s2);
            optionTxtView = 1;

        } else {
            if (optionTxtView == 1) {
                tv3.setText(s2);
                optionTxtView = 1;
            }
        }

        adapter.add(text.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(yourList);

Comment: I read something like an iterator. what is it?

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` works by returning data based on position. `Sets` do not have a notion of position; you have to iterate over the `Set` to find the element you want.

On the other hand, `Lists` do have a notion of position, this is why they play nicely with `ListView` and the `BaseAdapter` class.

Comment: can you give an example? an actual code will be highly appreciated. :)

Comment: What I am saying is that you should not use a `Set` to back a `ListVIew`

Comment: then what will i do now? :( i never used hashset.

Answer (score 0):

Adding ArrayList elements to a HashSet (Note: use LinkedHashSet if the order of elements matters):

```
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    list.add("Hello");
    list.add("Hello");
    list.add("World!");

    System.out.println(list); // [Hello, Hello, World!]

    set.addAll(list);

    System.out.println(set); // [Hello, World!]
```

Using your code, maybe you could try something like:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
//onCreate
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());

    HashSet<String> noDupesSet = new HashSet<String>();
    noDupesSet.addAll(wordlist);
    wordlist.clear();
    wordlist.addAll(noDupesSet);
    wordList.setAdapter(adapter);

//SEARCH
public void viewWord(View view) {
    s1 = search.getText().toString();
    s2 = dbHelper.getData(s1);

    if (optionTxtView == 0) {
      tv2.setText(s2);
        optionTxtView = 1;

    } else {
        if (optionTxtView == 1) {
            tv3.setText(s2);
            optionTxtView = 1;
        }
    }

    adapter.add(text.getText().toString());
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: can you d oit using my code please? I am still confuse on how it should be constructed. By the way, thank you for giving  codes :)

Comment: Try the edited version. Adds elements to set, then back to arraylist.